# Access IPhone in Finder

Tags: iphone, finder

Is there a way to access iPhone in Finder, similar to the way Windows can access it in Explorer? Going through some growing pains in doing things the "apple way" ...

Answer (score 1):

Generally without jailbreaking the device, no. Apple makes it quite difficult to access the filesystem of your iOS device - whether attempting to navigate directories on the device directly, or remotely from your computer.

However, there are certain programs recently made available which enable one to do so. For example, [**iFunBox**](http://www.i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/) is an iOS file management application for your desktop that allows you to browse and manipulate the filesystem *without jailbreaking the phone.*

Additionally, you may find it helpful to use **[iOS's Spotlight feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3636)** to quickly find and access content on your device:

> "To access Spotlight, swipe down on your home screen to reveal the search field."
>
> "Spotlight searches certain text fields in the content of your device for text beginning with your search phrase. It is not case-sensitive, so you can search using uppercase or lowercase letters and get the same results."

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do so for a while now, I think the only way to get a third party app like iExplorer and then find the file. If the file isn't using file sharing, you can make a backup of your phone and find the file in there.

But the only way to edit the files would be to make the iphone backup, then use a third party app (I recommend iExplorer) to find the file, then right click and choose show in finder, now you have the file and permission to edit it. once you are done, You need to restore your iphone to THAT backup, now your changes are saved.

Comment: iExplorer has a cool "mount as disk" feature for the directories on your iOS device. For example, you can mount the "Live Photos" album on your Finder as a disk.